# Installing Composer for subdomain - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I have installed composer on my cpanel(which has a global php version 5.6). Currently, i am in a subfolder which is under my sub-domain. My sub-domain has a php version 7. This subfolder contains my project. When i try to run my project, i`get a 500 internal error`

Looking in my error log in my cpanel, i see this error `Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos()`.  I tried this in my terminal `composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv` but i keep getting this
another error

> > This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.

I have upgraded the php version for my sub-domain but why is the composer not able to recognize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run composer in PHP7 mode for this like:

```
path/to/php7/php path/to/composer/composer.phar require symfony/polyfill-iconv
```

Or simply ignore PHP version requirement like:

```
composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: even after `composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv --ignore-platform-reqs` when i check ` php --ri iconv` my iconv is not present.

Comment: Yes i am able to see `symfony/polyfill-iconv` in the vendor folder but when i do `php --ri iconv` i get my iconv is not present

Comment: yes when i run `php --ri iconv` out of my sub-folder where i have my project, i get enabled but in the sub-folder it is not present

Comment: Well, that is another problem entirely. You should create a new question for that. And if this solution was helpful with this question, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Type php -v in console. This command show php version. If it shows old php, you can change default php version just execute:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

change to your php version number